# What image resizing libraries for .NET core are supported on Azure Web App Service?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core

What image resizing libraries are available for a .NET core application that is hosted on Azure Web App Services?

Found this blog that explains several libraries: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/.

Most of those libraries (except imagesharp) make use of native windows functionality like GDI, that isn't supported on Azure Web App Services according to this post: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions

At the moment I can resize images with ImageSharp but that library is still in beta and the performance isn't great at the moment.

Comment: Check [5 Reasons You Should Stop Using System.Drawing from ASP.NET](https://photosauce.net/blog/post/5-reasons-you-should-stop-using-systemdrawing-from-aspnet). It explains why ImageSharp is slow and how that can be fixed, but also points to MagicScaler and Mono's SkiaSharp.

Comment: Maaaan these are really out of date articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at SkiaSharp.

> SkiaSharp is a cross-platform 2D graphics API for .NET platforms based on Google's Skia Graphics Library. It provides a comprehensive 2D API that can be used across mobile, server and desktop models to render images.

- [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)

Comment: Will try it out on azure web app service and see if there are any hiccups. Will keep this post updated

Comment: Have you tried SkiaSharp on Azure Web App?  Did it work?

Comment: SkiaSharp works on azure web app without any problems

Comment: I couldn't find anything on SkiaSharp to help me resize an uploaded image on Razor NET Core webpage.

Comment: See for instance [Resize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skbitmap.resize) or [ScalePixels()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skbitmap.scalepixels).